# Will purchasing a booster pack on the Community Market and turning it into cards still have trade restrictions applied to it?

Tags: steam-trading-cards, steam-community-market

To my disappointment, Steam now prevents you from trading purchased items right away. I'm wondering if there is a way around this by purchasing a booster pack, then immediately opening it and trading the cards you get?

Will Steam allow this, or will the waiting period on trading still apply?

Comment: What's up with the downvote?

Comment: [Tim lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/193762).  Again.

Comment: @ardaozkal It's not trolling.  I'm making the point that asking for reasoning for a downvote is a lost cause; it's going to happen, and if someone wanted to give a reason, they would have.

Comment: @Frank Well, asking couldn't really hurt. I mean, it took about 10 seconds of my time and worst case scenario, they don't respond.

Comment: And they *would have already told you* if they wanted to.  It's a complete lost cause to do so.

Comment: @Frank, I think that's where we disagree. Anyways, this is a trivial debate anyways, so let's not bother continuing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 7 day trade-ban time is over on the booster pack, the trade-ban won't apply. But if it isn't over, it'll still apply, but it won't reset to ~7 days, the trade-ban will finish at the same time the booster pack will.

Answer (score 1):

Any item purchased on the Steam Community Market has a trade restriction applied to it immediately for 1 week, so no, you won't be able to bypass the trade restriction as that also applies to the cards unboxed that way.

Comment: @ardaozkal If your answers are in a couple of minutes of each other, no, they won't.  Even mentioning it is a waste of time, with answers showing up that quickly.

Comment: @ardaozkal Nothing wrong with answering, but don't assume that being first by a couple minutes entitles your answer to special privileges.  Yeah, we delete answers that don't add anything, but we also give a good faith exception within a time frame to be exempt from it.  There's no reason to threaten deletion just because you were first.  By two minutes.